# Using bash_profile variables in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, operating-system, environ

I am trying to hide my login credentials creating my variables in my .bash_profile. `export var = 'foo'` and accessing in jupyter notebook using `os.environ.get('var')`. The result is None.

In my normal IDE it is easy since my steps are:

```
> cd
> nano .bash_profile
> export var = 'foo'
```

settings.py

```
os.environ.get('var')

output: foo
```

From here, my IDE access that specific bash profile and returns what I requested.

How can I access the jupyter notebook bash profile and create variables in there? Thanks.